# Error in simple code

Tags: python-2.7

Beginner in Python Programming. I keep getting an error when I try to change the text of a label when a button is pressed.

```
#Label Text Command
def Print_Stories():
    Printing_Label["text"] = "Printing"

#Printing Label
Printing_Label = Label(app, height=5, width = 19, font = "Calibri 20", bd = 2, relief = 'groove').place(x=20, y=170)

#Print Button
Button1 = Button(app, text ="Print", command= Print_Stories).place(x=100, y=110)
```

The Error I get:

```
File "C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop\xxxxx.py", line 136, in Print_Stories
Printing_Label["text"] = "Printing"
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Grateful for any help

Comment: Are you sure `Label().place()` returns a label? Did you mean `Printing_Label = Label(); Printing_Label.place(...)`

Comment: That's what I intended to put. must have blanked out. Thanks for answering my question so quickly :D